# React - Volver atrás con las propiedades seleccionados en el formulario

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un formulario donde hago una llamada API para buscar elementos y los muestro en un row.

**Form**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Search extends Component{

    busquedaProducto = React.createRef();

    getData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const termino = this.busquedaProducto.current.value;
        this.props.datosBusqueda(termino);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.getData}>
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                        <input ref={this.busquedaProducto} type="text" className="form-control form-control-lg"
                               placeholder="Busca tu producto. Ejemplo : Rueda"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" value="Buscar..."/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Y luego muestro la ficha del producto con un botón de volver atrás.

**Ficha del producto**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Product extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            termino: '1',
            producto: [],
        }

    }

    consultarApi = (props) => {

        const product_id = this.props.location.state.product_id;
        const url = `http://api.local/api/products/${product_id}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => this.setState({ producto : result } ));
    }

    datosBusqueda = (termino) => {
        //console.log(termino);
        this.setState({
            termino
        }, () => {
            this.consultarApi();
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.consultarApi();
    }



    render() {

        let id = this.state.producto.id;
        let name = this.state.producto.name;

        return (

                <div className="app container" style={{backgroundColor: "whitesmoke", padding: "10px"}}>

                    <div className="blockquote text-left">
                        <img src={image_route} width="100" height="80" />
                    </div>

                    ID : { id } <br/>
                    Producto : { name } <br/>

                    <a onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()} href="#">Volver atrás</a>

                </div>

        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Product);
```

El botón de volver atrás funciona el problema que hace un "go back" pero me deja el formulario vacio sin el input que habia rellenado y por lo tanto sin valores.

Comment: Viendo tu código noté algo, en consultar la api no deberías usar  `this.props.location.state.product_id;` porque si intentarás acceder a la ruta del producto (o recargando) no funcionará porque se perdieron los parametros del link que estabas pasabdo. Para eso deberías usar los params, fijate que definimos las rutas `product/:id` en el router. Entonces, `react-router` sabe que lo que viene después de product es el id. Para acceder puedes a través de los parametros con : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams o `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: Hice una modificación al código para que veas como acceder al Param de la URL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer no es posible, por defecto, porque básicamente cuando desmontas el componente. Se borra esa instancia de memoria y no es posible recuperarla, este es un gran problema en las SPA

Entonces, debes buscar una manera de tener esos parametros de busqueda guardados y accederlos cuando la persona vuelva a entrar al componente. Para esto hay muchas opciones: `React Context`, `Redux`, `LocalStorage`, `SessionStorage`.

Yo haré mi ejemplo usando `React Context`,

Consigues el ejemplo funcionando en: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-frog-3fdqk

Igual puedes chequear la documentación: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Ahora, vamos al código,

Tendremos que crear el contexto. A mi me gusta hacerlo por separado:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, createContext } from "react";

export const ProductsContext = createContext(null);

const ProudctsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [productFilter, setProductFilter] = useState([]);
  return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ productFilter, setProductFilter }}>
      {children}
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useProducts = () => {
  const context = useContext(ProductsContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "Components using ProductsContext must be rendered within the Products Provider"
    );
  }

  return context;
};

export default ProudctsProvider;
```

En este código:

- Creamos el contexto con `createContext` (la información que guardaremos)
- Creamos el Provider (que es quien proveera la información que guardaremos) que recibe los hijos y los pinta (**SUPER IMPORTANTE**)
- Creamos un hook para acceder fácilmente a la información

Ahora, tenemos que modificar el App.js, para que use el contexto/provider:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ProductsProvider from "./ProductsProvider";
import Product from "./Product";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ProductsProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={Product} />
            <Route path="/" component={ProductList} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </ProductsProvider>
  );
}
```

Ahora, con esto, podemos guardar la información, nuestra lista se verá así:

```js
import React from "react";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";
import { useProducts } from "./ProductsProvider";

export default function ProductList(props) {
  const { productFilter, setProductFilter } = useProducts();
  const baseSearch = props.location.keepSearch ? productFilter : "";
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState(baseSearch);
  const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Product 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Product 2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Product 3" },
    { id: 4, name: "Product 4" }
  ];

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    setProductFilter(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="ProductList">
      Buscar:
      <input type="text" value={search} onChange={handleSearch} />
      {products
        .filter((product) => product.name.includes(search))
        .map((product) => (
          <ProductCard key={product.id} producto={product} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Fijate que tengo la opción de mantener los datos de busqueda o no mantenerlo (para cuando haces un link normal, se cargue el formulario vacio). Pero además, cada vez que modifican el bucador yo guardo el valor que buscan.

Finalmente, podremos hacer los links como se muestra en el archivo de Producto:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const productInfo = this.props.location.aboutProps || { product_id: id, product_name: 'GO TO API' };
    
    return (
      <div
        className="app container"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "whitesmoke", padding: "10px" }}
      >
        {productInfo.product_id} - {productInfo.product_name}
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <NavLink to="/" exact>
          Volver
        </NavLink>
        <br />
        <NavLink
          to={{
            pathname: `/`,
            keepSearch: true
          }}
          exact
        >
          Volver pero con Contexto
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```